# CKEditor and paths to plugin scripts

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ckeditor

I was using CKEditor with no problems on my site then moved the site from one directory to another -- /vmgdev to /vmg. Everything is working OK except ckeditor, which doesn't appear. It seems that ckeditor is failing to load the autogrow plugin scripts, as it's still looking at the old path. Disabling autogrow fixes the problem and ckeditor appears again. In the head of a page that uses the editor I still have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { 
 ... 
"loadPlugins": { "autogrow": { "name": "autogrow", "desc": "Autogrow plugin", "path": "/vmgdev/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/autogrow/", "default": "f" },
 ...;
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

How I can I fix the autogrow plugin path? In the form that allows me to change the ckeditor global profile the plugins path is set to %m/plugins and beneath this field it claims that %m is equal to %m - /vmg/sites/all/modules/ckeditor, but that's obviously not the path that's being used.

Thanks.

Comment: Remember to clear the cache on your Drupal server and the cache on your browser.

Comment: @nmc thanks! Clearing the drupal cache fixed it. Make your comment into an answer if you want some rep :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to clear the cache on your Drupal server as well as the cache on your browser.

Since ckeditor relies on a lot of javascript, I've found that often the browser caches the javascript and doesn't show the changes you've made even if you've refreshed the Drupal cache.